# Handling values with multiple items in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Supposed my dataframe

```
  Name  Value
0   A   apple
1   A   banana
2   A   orange
3   B   grape
4   B   apple
5   C   apple
6   D   apple
7   D   orange
8   E   banana
```

I want to show the items of each name.
(By removing duplicates)

output what I want

```
  Name  Values
0   A   apple, banana, orange
1   B   grape, apple
2   C   apple
3   D   apple, orange
4   E   banana
```

thank you for reading

Comment: `df.groupby('Name')['Value'].agg(', '.join)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed sample data with duplicates:

```
print (df)
   Name   Value
0     A   apple
1     A   apple
2     A  banana
3     A  banana
4     A  orange
5     B   grape
6     B   apple
7     C   apple
8     D   apple
9     D  orange
10    E  banana
```

If duplicates per both columns is necessary remove first use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then aggregate `join`:

```
df1 = (df.drop_duplicates(['Name','Value'])
         .groupby('Name')['Value']
         .agg(','.join)
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Name                Value
0    A  apple,banana,orange
1    B          grape,apple
2    C                apple
3    D         apple,orange
4    E               banana
```

If not removed duplicates output is:

```
df2 = (df.groupby('Name')['Value']
         .agg(','.join)
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
  Name                             Value
0    A  apple,apple,banana,banana,orange
1    B                       grape,apple
2    C                             apple
3    D                      apple,orange
4    E                            banana
```